# Ubuntu 14 / Win 8.1 Install Problem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I'm trying to return to Ubuntu on a new(er) computer after I had to switch to Mint on my old machine due to performance issues. The new machine is an HP pavillion G4 w/ 4gp memory and a 500GB HD. I can successfully run from live usb, although it cannot mount any of the windows drives.

I read :
[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

where the author describes how to install Ubuntu when it doesn't recognize the Windows 8 partitions. I've done all the pre-requisites, and still Ubuntu installer doesn't recognize the windows partitions. So now I'm down to the "Something else" method, and I'm confused with the language in this part:

> "You need to create at least 1 partition for the root system (Which shows as the symbol "/") and set it to Ext4, another for SWAP (Virtual Memory). The SWAP space can be as small as 128MB if you have a lot of ram or as high as 4GB. With this 2 partitions created based on the empty space you provided you should be ready to proceed. And one last one for the EFI part which should be around 100MB."

I get that I have to:

1. root, mounted at `/`, ext4, (of approx size 50GB)
2. swap, mounted at "swap", (of size approx 6GB or 1.5 x physical memory)
3. Home (optional)

My question is what is meant by the `"And one last one for the EFI part...?"` Does this mean another partition? if so, mount point etc.

Answer (score 0):

EFI partition is usually the firs one, so you can create setup like this /dev/sda1 (~200MB) of filesystem FAT32 and mount point /boot/efi 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition

Answer (score 0):

if you use uefi bios , you need an efi partition , and your win8 have already created one , and this efi partition doesn't need to monut , when you install , you just choose this partition to install efi loader file in it , it does the same thing when you install mbr in one partition for legacy bios